# Sorting date Time seconds with AM PM

Tags: jquery, momentjs

I have a issue with sorting the date. I tried earlier, but nothing works. I am also posting my fiddle here. can someone help me in editing my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danDian/b4q7h1fc/1/).

```
function sortAscending(a, b) { 
const dateA = moment($(a).find('.year').text(), 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss gm');
const dateB = moment($(b).find('.year').text(), 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss gm');

return dateA.isBefore(dateB) ? 1 : dateA.isAfter(dateB) ? -1 : 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a wrong token for the `AM` and `PM`, you should use `a` or `A`, see the [`documentation`](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

> Your return statement in the `sortAscending` function isn't wrong but it can be minified in just `return dateA.isBefore(dateB) ? 1 : 0;`.

Here a working example:

```js
function sortAscending(a, b) {
  const dateA = moment($(a).find('.year').text(), 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a');
  const dateB = moment($(b).find('.year').text(), 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a');
  return dateA.isBefore(dateB) ? 1 : 0;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#wrapper .cards').sort(sortAscending).appendTo('#wrapper');
});
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

<!-- one element -->
<div class="cards">
    <span class="display-number">01</span>
    <span class="year">21/07/2012 10:25:10 AM</span>
</div><!-- element -->

<!-- one element -->
<div class="cards">
    <span class="display-number">02</span>
    <span class="year">21/07/2012 10:25:23 AM</span>
</div><!-- element -->

<!-- one element -->
<div class="cards">
    <span class="display-number">03</span>
    <span class="year">21/07/2012 10:25:45 PM</span>
</div><!-- element -->

<!-- one element -->
<div class="cards">
    <span class="display-number">04</span>
    <span class="year">21/07/2012 10:25:08 PM</span>
</div><!-- element -->

<!-- one element -->
<div class="cards">
    <span class="display-number">05</span>
    <span class="year">21/07/2012 10:25:58 AM</span>
</div><!-- element -->

</div> <!--wrapper-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: yeahh this is exactly what I need.